# Setting VPN using Java

Tags: java, openvpn

I need to open a san box url while using file browse button in a web application. For that i planed to set VPN using Java code.I tried it google but could not find any solutions so for. Any Idea for this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do?  When you say "open a sandbox URL while using file browse button", I assume you're trying to list available files (and maybe retrieve contents of a file)?  If so, are you trying to access the file system of the server (web server?) or the client?

Either way, I think you need to consider some other options.

If you're looking to expose a directory tree of the server, I'd expose any details you need (directory tree and/or file contents) through a web service (JSON, XML, or otherwise) - and present that data back to the client - possibly using AJAX.  An immediate example that comes to mind is [phpVirtualBox](http://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/).  I can remotely mount virtual disks from the server on the server - all through a remote web browser using this approach.

If you're looking to expose a directory tree from the web client, you either need to use the browser's built-in file selector (using `<input type="file"...>`, or an applet - e.g. Java or Flash, if the browser-provided options don't provide the functionality that you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to list available images which is in a san box(server).

Comment: I could not  get the line " I can remotely mount virtual disks from the server on the server - all through a remote web browser using this approach."Could you tell it in another way?

Comment: Probably not the least confusing example that could be given, but basically, in VirtualBox (if operated from the server itself), I can browse to files on disk to load them.  The phpVirtualBox allows me to do the same remotely - while still viewing the directory listing on the same server, now remote.

Comment: Okay Thanks. I surf on the google about VirtualBox for Java as i am new to that concept.

Comment: VirtualBox really has nothing to do with Java.  It was just the first example that I could think of where a remote directory structure was presented through a web interface, similar to what you're asking for.